# Thunk + Redux (in React Native) : Can't get action to work

Tags: redux-thunk

I'm brand new to this stack.  I've seen quite a few other questions about this and have read the Thunk documentation but I can't stitch this together.

When I run the code below I get the error "Actions must be plain objects, use custom middleware for async actions" which is exactly the problem I'm trying to solve with Thunk.

My action looks like this:

`src/actions/recipes.js`

```
// this calls the API
function fetchApiGetRecipes() {
  return fetch('https://mywebsite.com/endpoint/', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + idToken
    }
  }).then((json) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'RECIPES_REPLACE',
      data: json
    })

  });
}

// this is passed into my container to use to refresh the recipe list
export function getRecipes() {    
  if (Firebase === null) return () => new Promise(resolve => resolve());

  if (Firebase.auth().currentUser !== null) {
          Firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {            
            // console.log(idToken);
            return dispatch => new Promise(resolve => fetchApiGetRecipes(idToken) )                  
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle error
          });

  } else {
    console.log("Null user");
  }

}
```

What is the correct syntax to use Thunk here and fix the error I'm getting when the app starts up?

EDIT:  I create the store like this:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistCombineReducers } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/es/storage'; // default: localStorage if web, AsyncStorage if react-native
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import reducers from '../reducers';

// Redux Persist config
const config = {
  key: 'root',
  storage,
  blacklist: ['status'],
};

const reducer = persistCombineReducers(config, reducers);

const middleware = [thunk];

const configureStore = () => {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__(),
    compose(applyMiddleware(...middleware)),
  );

  const persistor = persistStore(
    store,
    null,
    () => { store.getState(); },
  );

  return { persistor, store };
};

export default configureStore;
```

Comment: Can you post the code where you created the store as well? Looks like you haven't properly configured `redux-thunk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getRecipes` function doesn't return a function in the `if (Firebase.auth().currentUser !== null)` clause.

You need to return a function where you are just doing

```
Firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(/* forceRefresh */ true).then(function(idToken) {            
            // console.log(idToken);
            return dispatch => new Promise(resolve => fetchApiGetRecipes(idToken) )                  
          }).catch(function(error) {
            // Handle error
          });
```

The dispatch function (I assume is the intended one to return) is being returned in the `then` clause of the promise. That doesn't return the dispatch function to the outer method `getRecipies`. Hence the error

Answer (score 1):

probably you forgot pass `dispatch` to func args?

```
// you use dispatch in this func
function fetchApiGetRecipes() {...}

// you forget pass
return dispatch => new Promise(resolve => fetchApiGetRecipes(idToken) )
```

Comment: That will not cause any error as it's not mandatory to include all the arguments for the function being returned